# How can you avoid gitlab showing merge changes?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-merge

In my job we use gitlab for version control and code reviewing. My current issue is, if I am working on a branch and a major change that affects multiple files happens, I need to merge it. But then when I push, gitlab shows the merged changes from master along with my own changes under "changes", which makes code reviewing more difficult for the reviewer. How could I easily prevent gitlab from showing the merge changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rebase your local working branch or your PR before pushing it. And the diff of the PR should be based on master.
That way GL will only show the new commits.

More details here on the philosophy: https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/#mergepull-requests-with-gitlab-flow